# Select all users related to a project

Tags: jira-rest-api

I want to list all users related to a project.

```
https://company.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user/viewissue/search?
projectKey=MyProject&
username=.
```

This is the only method I found but it requires username filter ... and there seems not to be any "select all" option.